# Facebook New Feed RSS Stopped working from few hours AGO

Tags: android, facebook, rss, facebook-rss

i am using rss feed link as,

**https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=58975061171**

above link working well from last few days.. but today is suddenly stopped working.

any new link is now open for it ?

find one solution using graph but it requires user login !

Comment: why it was down voted? whats your problem? describe it so everyone can see that. and one more thing dear all down voter you have solution of it without graph api? if No than try it and than show your ans or comment instead of down voting.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook [deprecated public RSS feed for pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_90_day_deprecations).

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook graph api user feeds](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed)

https://graph.facebook.com/{user}/feed?access_token=your_access_token